# short Javascript program questions( erro output)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
const HIGH_AGE = 70, MAX_AGE = 120, BABIE_AGE=4, TEEN_AGE=16;

function main ()

{

 var age;  
    age = Number(prompt('Enter your age:')); //set prompt box ask user's age

    if (age < BABIE_AGE || age > MAX_AGE)//if user user's age are below "0" or above "120" 
        alert('Please Enter Age Within the Range between 0-120!');//output: must enter age in valid age range

    else if (isNaN(age) == true || !age)
        alert('please enter a valid entry');   

    else if ((age >= HIGH_AGE) || (age >= 0 && age <= BABIE_AGE))//if age between 0-4 or above 70 
        alert('You may travel for free');//output: they can travel for free     

    else if (age >= CHILDREN_AGE && age <= TEEN_AGE )//if user's age are under 16 
        alert('You may travel with a half price ticket');//output they can travel for half-price

    else 
        alert('You must travel with a full price ticket'); //others all travel with full price
}
```

Comment: So, you've posted your short program. But what is your *question*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited your function. You can try it.

```
const HIGH_AGE = 70, MAX_AGE = 120, BABIE_AGE=0, CHILDREN_AGE=4, TEEN_AGE=16;

function main () { 

var age;

    while(/^(?:[1-9]+(?:[0-9]+)?|0)$/.test((age = prompt('Enter your age:'))) == false) {
    alert("You must enter number!");
}

age = Number(age);

if (age < BABIE_AGE || age > MAX_AGE)//if user's age are below "0" or above "120" 
    alert('Please enter age within the range between 0-120!');//output: must enter age in valid age range

else if ((age >= HIGH_AGE) || (age >= BABIE_AGE && age <= CHILDREN_AGE))//if age between 0-4 or above 70 
    alert('You may travel for free');//output: they can travel for free

else if (age >= CHILDREN_AGE && age <= TEEN_AGE )//if user's age are under 16 
    alert('You may travel with a half price ticket');//output they can travel for half-price

else 
    alert('You must travel with a full price ticket'); //others all travel with full price      

}
```

Look at this code:

```
while(/^(?:[1-9]+(?:[0-9]+)?|0)$/.test((age = prompt('Enter your age:'))) == false) {
    alert("You must enter number!");
}
```

Here is working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/varrwx32/14/

Comment: hey georgi when i enter "1" it output please enter a number, where is should said you may travel for free

Comment: thanks Georgi, however when i put 0 in it says my input was invalid, babies thats under 1 year old are 0

Comment: Check it again. I fixed this.

Comment: Thank you so much georgi, i think I am not allowed to use while, because the lecture said use only conditional statement, so iv added this to my code, but I'm getting the same erro when i enter 0 it gives me erro? do you know anything wrong with it?

Comment: There was a little problem with regular expression. Check the code again. Are you allowed to use recursion? We can use recursion instead while loop.

Comment: I'm only allowed to use conditional statement, i have updated the code and add:else if (isNaN(age) == true || !age)
    alert('please enter a valid entry');  but when i enter 0 it still output error

Comment: the new code works fine, but only when input is '0' not sure where the problem is :s

Comment: The last version will work as expected. :) I did not change it from me last comment.

Comment: yeah it works, but when i put 0 it still says erro, i want it to be you can travel for free?

Comment: Hmm. It working properly under firefox and chrome with 0 also. What is your browser?

Comment: I writing from my phone now. It working under Android Chrome also - chek jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it is a number:

```
age = prompt('Enter your age:');

if (age == +age) alert("Please insert a number!");
else {
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: use `isNan` instead, if you enter 0 then it will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function:

```
if (isNaN(age)) {
    // ... age is not valid number
}
```

`Number(prompt('...'))`  will return `NaN` value if it can't interpret input as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution (the only one i can think of this quickly), is to use parseInt();
I hope this helps.